# Renamed files to MD5 hashes, how to do so for one directory?

Tags: terminal, sudo

I used this command and ended up damaging several directories' worth of files, not system-critical files on macOS Monterey 12.2.1, MacBook Pro 13-inch 2020:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv $1 "${1%.*}.$(md5 -q $1).${1##*.}"' bash {} \;
```

It moved them from their directories to `/Users/` and renamed them to their md5 hashes, I did this command:

```
cd Users/USERNAME/Desktop/mytest
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv $1 "${1%.*}.$(md5 -q $1).${1##*.}"' bash {} \;
```

Isn't this a highly dangerous command like `sudo` and how should I have used it for files specific to one directory only?

Comment: Unix commands in general can be dangerous if you aren't careful. I always recommend using `mv -i` or `mv -f` with any sort of bulk/automated move, to keep `mv` from silently and irreversibly overwriting files if there's a name conflict. Also, add `echo` before the `mv` command to get a "dry run" where it'll print what it'd be executing if you remove the `mv`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Thank you. I didn't know of echo mv, mv -i or mv -f, I irreversibly overwrote files there.

Answer (score 1):

For one directory only you can just run the `mv` part in a for loop with appropriate parameters, or use `-maxdepth 1` with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
    -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.*}.$(md5 -q $1).${1##*.}"' bash {} \;
```

PS: `sudo` allows you run commands as another user, it doesn‘t protect you from harm.